# Java method errors

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm new to Java and was trying to compile a program but there's a problem with on of my methods.  Here is the code for the one that's giving me trouble.

```
        public String nameCard (); {
    String namedSuit;
    String namedCard;
    String namedFace;
    if (this.suit==0) {
        namedSuit="Spades";
    }
    if (this.suit==1) {
        namedSuit="Hearts";
    }
    if (this.suit==2) {
        namedSuit="Clubs";
    }
    if (this.suit==3) {
        namedSuit="Diamonds";
    }
    if (this.face==1 || this.face>10) {
        if (this.face==1) {
            namedFace="Ace";
        }
        if (this.face==11) {
            namedFace="Jack";
        }
        if (this.face==12) {
            namedFace="Queen";
        }
        if (this.face==13) {
            namedFace="King";
        }
        namedCard=namedFace + " of " + namedSuit;
    }
    else if (this.face>1 && this.face<=10) {
        namedCard=this.face + " of " + namedSuit;
    }
    return namedCard;
}
```

The cmd window keeps returning "Card.java:70(the first line I have here): error: missing method, body, or declare abstract"  and "Card.java:104: error: return outside method" for the last line with text.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read this again, carefully: `public String nameCard (); {`. You'll see the problem :).

Comment: if you formatted your code in a sane manner this would have been pretty obvious what the typo was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semicolon is an empty statement. Remove it in your method declaration. This

```
public String nameCard (); {
```

Should be

```
public String nameCard () {
```